# Can't get all values of dynamic form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="custom_options" >
<div class="options_group">
    <div class="form-group  col-md-12 ">
        <label class="control-label" for="opt_group">group</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="opt_group" value="" autocomplete="true">
    </div>
    <div id="props" class="form-group bg-grey">
        <div class="form-group  col-md-5 ">
            <label class="control-label" for="opt_title">title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="opt_title" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group  col-md-1 ">
            <label class="control-label" for="opt_procent">procent</label>
            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" name="opt_procent" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group  col-md-6 ">
            <label class="control-label" for="opt_title">image</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="opt_image"value="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="props" class="form-group bg-grey">
        <div class="form-group  col-md-5 ">
            <label class="control-label" for="opt_title">title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="opt_title"  value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group  col-md-1 ">
            <label class="control-label" for="opt_procent">procent</label>
            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" name="opt_procent" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group  col-md-6 ">
            <label class="control-label" for="opt_title">image</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="opt_image" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each **options_group** could be dynamically added, and those **#props** (inputs: opt_title, opt_procent, opt_image) also could be dynamically added.

I need to get data from all this fields JSON

```
{
"group_name_from_Opt_Group_Input":[
        { "title":"Foo", "procent":"15" },
        { "title":"Bar", "procent":"5" }
        ]
}
```

as far as I found out the easiest way in this case is to generate JSON by my own script, but I can't get the props I needed.

I tried this:

```
    function opt_convert(){
    var data='';
    $('#custom_options').find('.options_group').each(function() {
        let groupname = $(this).find("input[name='opt_group']").val();

        alert(groupname);
    }).find('#props').each(function() {
            let name = $(this).find("input[name='opt_title']").val();
            let procent = $(this).find("input[name='opt_procent']").val();
            let image = $(this).find("input[name='opt_image']").val();
            alert(name);
    });

    document.getElementById("options").value = data;
}
```

Comment: More importantly, IDs are supposed to be unique. You can't have multiple `id="props"`. Use classes.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Actually you can have multiple fields with the same name. This is required for radio buttons, since the names define the groups. It's also common to repeat `name="field[]"` to create arrays of values.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, you're right, but they you run into parallel arrays. If there is a field that accepts multiple inputs, it will be difficult to distinguish between the "values" of each "object".

Comment: Looks like now it works, Thank you/ the problem was in ID instead of class. Didn't know that JQ really takes care about it

Answer (score 0):

The loop to get the array of objects needs to be nested inside the loop that finds the option groups, not parallel to it. Use the group name as the key of the object, then use `.map()` to return the objects with all the input values.

```js
function opt_convert() {
  let data = {};
  $('#custom_options').find('.options_group').each(function() {
    let groupname = $(this).find("input[name='opt_group']").val();
console.log(groupname);
    data[groupname] =
      $(this).find('.props').map(function() {
        let name = $(this).find("input[name='opt_title']").val();
        let procent = $(this).find("input[name='opt_procent']").val();
        let image = $(this).find("input[name='opt_image']").val();
        return {
          name,
          procent,
          image
        };
      }).get();
  });
  console.log(data);
}
$("#doit").click(opt_convert);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="custom_options">
  <div class="options_group">
    <div class="form-group  col-md-12 ">
      <label class="control-label" for="opt_group">group</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="opt_group" value="" autocomplete="true">
    </div>
    <div class="props form-group bg-grey">
      <div class="form-group  col-md-5 ">
        <label class="control-label" for="opt_title">title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="opt_title" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group  col-md-1 ">
        <label class="control-label" for="opt_procent">procent</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" name="opt_procent" value="0">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group  col-md-6 ">
        <label class="control-label" for="opt_title">image</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="opt_image" value="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="props form-group bg-grey">
      <div class="form-group  col-md-5 ">
        <label class="control-label" for="opt_title">title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="opt_title" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group  col-md-1 ">
        <label class="control-label" for="opt_procent">procent</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" name="opt_procent" value="0">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group  col-md-6 ">
        <label class="control-label" for="opt_title">image</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="opt_image" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="doit">Show data</button>
```